# How to create a self join cartesian product of a set with java stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a set of string like:

```java
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"));
```

I require if a new set having **cartesian** with itself

i.e. `["AA", "AB", "AC","BA", "BB", "BC","CA", "CB", "CC"]`

How do I do that using Java stream API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do below code:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"));

Set<String> cartesianSet = set
            .stream()
            .map(x-> set
                    .stream()
                    .map(y-> x+y)
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet()))
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        System.out.println(cartesianSet);//[AA, BB, CC, AB, BC, AC, CA, BA, CB]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)) as:

```
final Set<String> result = set.stream()
           .flatMap(x -> set.stream().map(y -> x+y))
           .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/xg5pBZ)

Comment: Thanks. But I required a Set

Comment: Just change it to `Collectors.toSet` in that case.